# Docker NFS Volume Permission Denied

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, nfs, docker-volume, openmediavault

Firstly, I am very new to NFS and the Linux world.

I am trying to migrate my docker swarm containers from using local volumes, to a shared volume on nfs.
I have a server with open media vault installed and I have a NFS share of /mariadb exposed which is accessible through the showmount command.
When trying to create the deployment using docker stack deploy, or docker volume create, I get a permission denied error from the deployment:

```
ERROR: for pi_mariadb_1  Cannot create container for service mariadb: open /var/lib/docker/volumes/testnfs2/_data: permission denied
```

For docker volume create I am running the following:

```
 docker volume create --name testnfs2 --driver local \
--opt type=nfs4 \
--opt o=addr=192.168.8.123,rw,noatime,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,tcp,timeo=14 \
--opt device=:/mariadb
```

My open media vault share setting is shown below:

[image: Open media vault share]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue, or may be able to guide me to troubleshooting why it is not working?

Comment: though, doesnt' the helptext underneath shared folder say "The share will be accessible at /export/."?  You might want to try `device=:/export/mariadb` instead of `device=:/mariadb` (not sure about the cli syntax though, I am always declaring volumes in the docker-compse.yml)

Comment: I am happy to do it in either method, to be honest would rather compose. Could you show me how you would do it in compose? I thought /export was for nfs v3 and below?

Comment: @Metin just tried with /export and get this:ERROR: for mariadb  Cannot create container for service mariadb: failed to mount local volume: mount :/export/mariadb:/var/lib/docker/volumes/testnfs2/_data, flags: 0x400, data: addr=192.168.8.123,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,tcp,timeo=14: no such file or directory

Comment: just for the sake of simplicity, you might want to figure out the exported mounts from the shell first. Something like  `sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.8.123:/export /mnt/export` (assumed /mnt/export exists on your host). Once you made this work you can start to figure out the set of filesystem permissions required.